# Unix command for picking out run commands

Tags: linux, bash

I am relatively new to linux environment. My doubt is this:
 I run a lot of commands of various types , so when ever i want to rerun a old one i have to look through the entire history. is there any bash command that displays just the commands that begin with a particular combination of characters( my case here is i just want a list of all the ./ eg: ./ifv_script , ./run_regression i've run from the terminal)

Comment: This is really not a question for Stackoverflow, but have a look at Ctrl-R :-)

Comment: Asked a zillion times over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three methods:

- You can grep your current history, e.g.:

  `$ history | grep ifv`
- You can also recall commands from the history by typing <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and then type a few characters from the command.
- Finally you can grep your saved history file for older invocations from previous sessions, e.g.:

  `$ grep ifv ~/.bash_history`

Answer (score 2):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>, and you will [enter into `reverse-i-search` mode](http://ruslanspivak.com/2010/11/20/bash-history-reverse-intelligent-search/).

Now you can type a few characters that appear anywhere in the command and bash will start finding matches.

Answer (score 0):

Final approach (bash only):

`history | grep term`